# Kubernetes cluster still running even after deleting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, ansible

I created a Kubernetes cluster using ansible-playbook command below

```
ansible-playbook kubectl.yaml --extra-vars "kubernetes_api_endpoint=<Path to aws load balancer server>"
```

Now I have deleted the cluster using command

```
kubectl config delete-cluster <Name of cluster>
```

But still EC2 nodes are running, I tried to manually stop them but they start again automatically (expected because they are running in a cluster)

Is there any way by which I can detach the nodes from the cluster or delete the cluster in total?

Kubectl config view shows below message

> apiVersion: v1
>   clusters: []
>   contexts:
>   - context:
>      cluster: ""
>      user: ""
>    name: default-context
>   current-context: default-context
>   kind: Config
>   preferences: {}
>   users:
>   - name: cc3.k8s.local
>     user:
>      token: cc3.k8s.local

This means there is no cluster.
I want to delete the cluster in total and start fresh.

Comment: Please provide more details as to what the ansible playbook does. Does it provision new nodes and then deploy k8s on top of them ?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same problem.  You need to delete the autoscaling group that spawns the worker nodes, which for some reason isn't deleted when you delete the EKS cluster.

Open the AWS console (console.aws.amazon.com), navigate to the EC2 dashboard, then scroll down the left pane to "Auto Scaling Groups".  Deleting the autoscaling group should stop the worker nodes from endlessly spawning.  You may also want to click on "Launch Configurations" and delete the template as well.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The `delete-cluster` command does this :

> delete-cluster  Delete the specified cluster from the kubeconfig

It will only delete the context from your `~/.kube/config` file. Not delete the actual cluster.

You will need to write a different script for that or go into the AWS console and simply delete the nodes.

Comment: When I am closing it from the aws console it starts new nodes again.

Comment: Then you need to delete the kubernetes cluster first. Is it an EKS cluster? You need to kill that before the ec2 instances or it will keep recreating them.

Comment: i have already deleted my cluster there is no cluster now when I type: kubectl config view
i get this 
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: ""
    user: ""
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: cc3.k8s.local
  user:
    token: cc3.k8s.local

Answer (score 0):

As @Jason mentioned `delete-cluster` is not an option for you if you want to delete cluster completely.

It would be better if you put ansible playbook file content which creates cluster, then we can see how it creates cluster on AWS.

Best and easiest option for me, you can create also simple playbook file to delete cluster by changing relevant module's state to `absent` in playbook.

Or if it uses EKS, then you can [configure your aws command line](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) then simply run i.e `aws eks delete-cluster --name devel`. For more info [click](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/delete-cluster.html#examples)

If it uses Kops, then you can run `kops delete cluster --name <name> --yes`
For more info about Kops CMD [click](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/commands.md)

If you still need help, please put ansible playbook file to question by editing.

Answer (score 0):

check your autoscaling. Due to autoscaling group, the ec2 instacne keep spinning. So, delete the autoscalling group and check